# How to get Local User Accounts on Log on Screen instead of domain controller users

Tags: sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2008-r2

I had installed SharePoint2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with local user Account with Administrator Privilege. Then I installed domain controller and active directory using command "dcpromo". After installation system was restarted and log on pages were showing domain controller users. On logging in as domain controller administrator, I was not able to access SharePoint2010 application as the domain controller administrator doesn't have permission to access content database of SharePoint2010.

```
  So in order to get SharePoint2010 application running, I need to log in as local user administrator. I removed domain controller and active directory services. After system restart, log on page is showing me some local user account but not the administrator account using which the SharePoint2010 was installed.

  In User Accounts folder I can see that "Administrator" account.

  Can somebody guide me how do I get that account working again?

  Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to reconfigure your SharePoint setup by running the the SharePoint configuration wizard and provide a domain user credentials in wizard